# Clustering an ordinal variable with unequal interval size

Tags: clustering, ordinal-data

I am interested in clustering a mixed type dataset and therefore I have found the package "clustMixType" in R [Link to package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clustMixType/clustMixType.pdf). I want to cluster numerical, categorical and ordinal variables. My original data set has an ordinal unequal size interval variable age (0 - 12, 13 - 18, 19 - 25, 26 - 90) which is problematic to cluster due to its nature.

The linked package description includes some generated data set:

```
datasim <- function(n = 100, k.ord = 2, muk = 1.5){
clusid <- rep(1:4, each = n)
# numeric
mus <- c(rep(-muk, n),
rep(-muk, n),
rep(muk, n),
rep(muk, n))
x1 <- rnorm(4*n) + mus
# ordered factor
mus <- c(rep(-muk, n),
rep(muk, n),
rep(-muk, n),
rep(muk, n))
x2 <- rnorm(4*n) + mus
# ordered factor
quants <- quantile(x2, seq(0, 1, length.out = (k.ord+1)))
quants[1] <- -Inf
quants[length(quants)] <- Inf
x2 <- as.ordered(cut(x2, quants))
x <- data.frame(x1, x2)
return(x)
}
n <- 100
x <- datasim(n = n, k.ord = 10, muk = 2)
```

Have I understood it correctly that in the generated data set from above, the "x2" variable is a an ordered, categorical variable with levels representing unequal intervals? The author then procedes to use gower's distance on the generated data set.

Is there anything one can do to cluster an ordinal variable that is also of unequal interval size (like my age variable)? I have been thinking of turning the age variable into a categorical ordinal variable with levels 1,2,3,4 even though it means loss of information. Can one do that?